# System tray displayMessage() not showing

Tags: java, swing, system-tray

So what I want is when my program runs (It's a system tray) one of those small notification problems show up at the bottom right of the screen. I tried.

```
trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Title", popup);
trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
trayIcon.displayMessage("Title", "MESSAGE HERE", TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR) //THIS IS THE LINE THAT SHOULD SHOW THE MESSAGE
```

Where should it be for it to run when the program runs and is that the correct method with the correct parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you had a read on [How to Use the System Tray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)?

However

Check this minimal example:

After `tray.add(trayIcon);` than show your message.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public Test() throws Exception {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new Test();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() throws Exception {
        createAndShowTray();
    }

    private void createAndShowTray() throws Exception {
        //Check the SystemTray is supported
        if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
            return;
        }

        //retieve icon form url and scale it to 32 x 32
        final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(
                new URL("http://www.optical-illusions.in/illusions/blue_rotation_optical_illusion.jpg")), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB, 32, 32));

        //get the system tray
        final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

        try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
        }

        trayIcon.displayMessage("Title", "MESSAGE HERE", TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR); //THIS IS THE LINE THAT SHOULD SHOW THE MESSAGE

    }

    private static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int type, int IMG_WIDTH, int IMG_HEIGHT) {
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
        g.dispose();

        return resizedImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see what I was doing wrong, I had to add it after the tray.add(trayIcon); try catch statement. Makes sense, thanks.

Comment: I did this and still is not working, weird thing, I got the code from another proyect which had it working  so I do not understand what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

Go to the little action center and click "manage notificaitons"
then scroll down in the settings until you get to the

[image]

It didn't work when I had it in a loop so I just tried putting an additional statement outside the loop and then it worked. Yay!