# Multiple messageDialog's opening up when only one should

Tags: java, swing, dialog

So I have a system tray and I have this code.

```
MenuItem help = new MenuItem ("Help");
help.addActionListener(selectedListener);
```

And then the code for the selectedListener is

```
} else if (pressed.equals("Help")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "MESSAGE HERE", "TITLE", 1);
}
```

The problem is that when I select the item "Help" in the system tray the messageDialog will come up but when I hit "OK" another one comes up, how can I stop this from happening and only one showing up even after "OK" is hit?

```
MenuItem help = new MenuItem("Help");
help.addActionListener(selectedListener);//HERE
//
MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit");
//
takeSS.addActionListener(selectedListener);
hotKey.addActionListener(selectedListener);
version.addActionListener(selectedListener);
changeLog.addActionListener(selectedListener);
help.addActionListener(selectedListener);
exit.addActionListener(selectedListener);
```

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) as its hard to guess what could be wrong unless having the full code, your problem does not seeem to originate from the above code

Comment: Posted the full code.

Comment: @kleopatra thats one things thats confused the crap out of me, check the [oracle tutorial for SystemTray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html) all components used are AWT, perhaps they must be because *System Tray* is not connected to Swing GUI which is lightweight?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp oops - overlooked the system tray ;-) Not entirely certain, but think you are right

Comment: @kleopatra its fine :) I just noticed this yesterday when answering the same OPs [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383829/system-tray-displaymessage-not-showing). They also state *The add() method can throw an `AWTException` if the operating system or the Java runtime determines that the icon cannot be added to the system tray.* which only makes me believe my above comment more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add `ActionListener` - *selectedListener* twice to *Help* `MenuItem`:

```
MenuItem help = new MenuItem("Help");
help.addActionListener(selectedListener);//HERE
//
MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit");
//
takeSS.addActionListener(selectedListener);
hotKey.addActionListener(selectedListener);
version.addActionListener(selectedListener);
changeLog.addActionListener(selectedListener);
help.addActionListener(selectedListener);// AND HERE
exit.addActionListener(selectedListener);
```

remove one and it will work as expected.